# Does google chrome 23 or firefox 17 supports CSS3-Layout?

Tags: css, layout

Does google chrome 23 or firefox 17 supports CSS3-Layout?
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's not supported by any browsers as of yet.

You can use caniuse.com to get an idea of what's supported in which browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#search=layout

Flexbox however, is supported in Chrome and Opera, but only partially in Firefox.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/